# how to disable the particular step in step header in angular mat stepper

Tags: angular

I have  a scenario when it is `edit-mode` ,I need to disable the second-step in step header of `mat-horizontal` stepper, I have tried to use the pointer events , but it is disabling the entire step header. I have also tried other ways but haven't found any solution.

```html
 <mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="receiptInfoData" errorMessage="Receipt Info is required.">
      <ng-template class="label" matStepLabel> Receipt Info</ng-template>
      <app-receipt-info (receiptInfoData)="completeReceiptInfoEvent($event,stepper)" [receiptData]="receiptInfoData"></app-receipt-info>
    </mat-step>
  
    <mat-step  errorMessage="Case Info is required.">
      <ng-template  matStepLabel>Case Info</ng-template>
      <app-case-info  *ngIf="receiptInfoData.purchaseOrder" (caseData)="completeCasesInfoEvent($event, stepper)" [receiptWithCaseInfoData]="receiptInfoData"></app-case-info>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step  errorMessage="Report Damage Container is required.">
      <ng-template class="label" matStepLabel>Report Damage Container </ng-template>
      <app-damage-info  *ngIf="receiptInfoData.purchaseOrder" (damageInfoData)="showReceiptSummary($event,stepper)" [receiptWithDamageInfoData]="damageInfo"></app-damage-info>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step errorMessage="Summary is required.">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
      <app-receipt-summary *ngIf="receiptInfoData.purchaseOrder" [receiptSummary]="receiptInfoData"></app-receipt-summary>
      <div class="btn-action"> <button mat-button matStepperNext size="sm" style="margin: 15px;" (click)="resetStepper(stepper)" class="mat-red" >Reset</button></div>
    </mat-step>
  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Comment: So you want to disable only second step of the stepper but not all of them? I think more clarification is needed

Comment: yes i just want to disable the second step in step  header

Answer (score 0):

Use a `linear stepper` with `completed=false` steps. When the user presses the button, it completes the step and move to the next one.

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper linear #stepper>
  <mat-step completed="false">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 1</ng-template>
    <app-some-child (nextClicked)="nextClicked($event)" ></app-some-child>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Step 2</ng-template>
    <app-some-other-child></app-some-other-child>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;

  nextClicked(event) {
    // complete the current step
    this.stepper.selected.completed = true;
    // move to next step
    this.stepper.next();
  }
}
```